# Fail to redirect in Flask under a post request

Tags: redirect, flask

I am working on a small website about food written by Flask. However, I have trouble with redirecting users to a new page after they type in something in the search bar and then click the search button.

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def home():

    if request.method == "POST":
        search      = request.form['search']
        print(search)

        sql_search  = 'SELECT Food.name,Food.area,Food.price,Food.description,Food.available_amount,Food.score,AVG_PRICE,AVG_SCORE,User.selling_score FROM Food LEFT JOIN(SELECT Food.name, Food.area ,AVG(Food.price) AS AVG_PRICE,AVG(Food.score) AS AVG_SCORE FROM Food GROUP BY Food.name, Food.area) NEW_FOOD ON Food.name = NEW_FOOD.name AND Food.area = NEW_FOOD.area LEFT JOIN User ON Food.maker_id = User.id WHERE Food.name LIKE "%s" ORDER BY Food.price,Food.score DESC,User.selling_score DESC' % search

        search_list = db.session.execute(sql_search).fetchall()
        search_l    = process_dict(search_list, attr_search)
        print(search_l)
        return redirect(url_for('test'), code = 303)

    return render_template('home.html')
```

This is the output from the terminal after I search "curry" on the homepage.

```
curry
[{'name': 'curry', 'area': 61801, 'price': 6.0, 'description': 'nice', 'available_amount': 1, 'score': 5.0, 'AVG_PRICE': 6.0, 'AVG_SCORE': 5.0, 'seller_score': 0.0}, {'name': 'curry', 'area': 61820, 'price': 8.0, 'description': 'ok', 'available_amount': 2, 'score': 5.0, 'AVG_PRICE': 8.666666666666666, 'AVG_SCORE': 4.0, 'seller_score': 0.0}, {'name': 'curry', 'area': 61820, 'price': 8.0, 'description': 'excellent', 'available_amount': 2, 'score': 4.0, 'AVG_PRICE': 8.666666666666666, 'AVG_SCORE': 4.0, 'seller_score': 0.0}, {'name': 'curry', 'area': 61820, 'price': 10.0, 'description': 'excellent', 'available_amount': 1, 'score': 3.0, 'AVG_PRICE': 8.666666666666666, 'AVG_SCORE': 4.0, 'seller_score': 0.0}]
10.193.20.119 - - [31/Mar/2018 20:40:41] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 303 -
10.193.20.119 - - [31/Mar/2018 20:40:41] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200
```

Although the terminal shows that it sends a get request to the page I want to redirect to, my page actually has no change. Does anyone have some ideas about what is going wrong with my code?

And this is the code for my simple test page:

```
@app.route('/test')
# @login_required
def test():
    return "hello"
```

Comment: The terminal shows that the redirect is happening and your browser is making a GET request to /test. You haven't shown the code the defines the "test" endpoint - what should be happening in that route that isn't happening?

Comment: "test" is a simple page printing out "hello"

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem - the browser shows "hello" for me.

Comment: Could this be a problem of the difference in different browsers?

Comment: Possibly - it's certainly nothing in the flask app causing this

Comment: and just want to double check that you also return a redirect under a post request?

Comment: confirmed - same as in your example code

Comment: OK, Thank you very much. Maybe I should test my code on a different browser~